# <lightning:datatable> with right-to-left does not display good

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, rtl

I am using [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) and it works ok for my english, left-to-right display.

But for my right-to-left display - there are a few problems:

1. on the table header there is a column added to the right, but it is not added to the tbody itself.
2. the columns themselves are still aligned left-to-right so the column-resize and the action buttons are still on the right of the column text.

[image]

**CODE**

I use the DIR="RTL" in my markup to set the html to right-to-left:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="accountContacts-list"
                         data="{!v.data}"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         keyField="id"
                         maxRowSelection="1"
                         selectedRows="{!v.selectedIds}" />
</div
```

**QUESTION**

Is there any solution to make `lightning:datatable` work in right-to-left?

Comment: `iconPosition` and `menuAlignment` can be modified to `left` or `right` as per the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm). We may need custom styling for rest

Comment: the main problem is the added header-column, @Thamilan what do you mean by "We may need custom styling for rest"? what should I do?

Comment: I meant the CSS. But isn't the `menuAlignment` working?

Comment: it works but fixes only the action buttons menu - nothing else. do you have a specific css that fixes this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug so there is no real good solution.

But I have found a workaround that is good enough for my use case.

The problem appears to be because all `<th>` html elements are defined as `text-align: left`, and inside the html table in the `lightning:datatable` component, the table columns are defined as `th`.

So I did a little css hack - it is not best practice, but as a workaround with 1 line of css code, it is good enough as long as lightning does not support full RTL:

I have added to the surrounding `div` element a unique css name (myUniqueTable):

```
<div dir="rtl" class="myUniqueTable">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="accountContacts-list"
                         data="{!v.data}"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         keyField="id"
                         maxRowSelection="1"
                         selectedRows="{!v.selectedIds}" />
</div>
```

then in the css file I have added:

```
.THIS .myUniqueTable th {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

So now all `th` elements under `myUniqueTable` className would be right aligned. that totally solved my problem